# Upload files directly from system to web server without using html form in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am reading an excel file and inserting excel data to wordpress post by php code. I have also a folder of images in my system and I want to upload those images to wordpress and assign those images to post as featured image one by one. Image name is same as post title in order to get related post image from the folder.

```
$dir = "/images/";

// Open a directory, and read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)){
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
      echo "filename:" . $file . "<br>";
    }
    closedir($dh);
  }
}
```

this code is used for read directory, how can I get images name from the folder and upload it to server

The code used to upload files to wordpress media is below

```
if ($_FILES) {
                        foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                            if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                                return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
                            }
                            $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $userid );
                            $attach_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attach_id ); 
                        }       
                    }
                    set_post_thumbnail( $listingid, $attach_id );
```

Now I want to uploads files from any folder not from $_FILES array

Comment: *"Urgent help needed"* - I feel the pressure too. Last minute details are the worse, aren't they? - This means, don't wait till the last minute to ask for help. Show some code with the areas you're having difficulties with.

Comment: I have added the code, now you can check what I want to create

Comment: You do realize the PHP code in the first block will not run on the client, right?  What is your architecture? Uploading from one webserver to another, or are you trying to take files from the client (which will not work)?

Comment: I want to upload files from client side (my pc) to server side (wordpress)

Comment: @James That isn't true.  `<input type="file" name="mutipleFiles" multiple="multiple" />`

Comment: @Brad HTML5 to the rescue, I'm glad that is now possible, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I dont get something, maybe i misunderstand the question, but you want it as a featured image, so why dont you just select it when you create the new post? there are plugins what you can use to attach multiple too

Comment: I have csv (excel sheet) of post that contain min 3000 posts data, I am uploading those post via my php code I have created and now I also want to attach a featured image to post.

Comment: I don't want to attach the image one by one by opening the post. I want to get the image from the directory, upload it to wordpress media and attach that image to wordpress post

Answer (score 0):

I have create the code to get the images name from folder and upload it to wordpress media uploader.

```
$dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )."Images/"; //image folder in the wordpress plugin directory, you can change this to your own

$list = glob($dir."*.*",GLOB_NOSORT); // read the images directory to get all images arrays

    //create $file array with the indexes show below
$file["name"] =$list[0];// get the first image path and name from $list[0]
$file["type"] = 'image/jpeg';
$file["size"] = filesize( $file["name"] );// get image size
$file["tmp_name"] =$list[0];
$file["error"] =1;
    //upload image to wordpress upload folder with wp_upload_bits() function 
    //but wp_upload_bits() function didn't return image ID it return image path and url.
    //I want image ID in order to attach image ID to wordpress post as featured image
$upload_image = wp_upload_bits($list[0], null, file_get_contents($list[0]));

    //get to upload image ID, we use wp_handle_upload() function but it is giving max file size error on my side
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $file, $upload_overrides );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem and below is the final code of my wordpress plugin.
1- Input excel file for wordpress post (contain post title, desc and image name)
2- Images folder

The html form to import post data into wordpress

```
<h2>Upload the xlsx file to Import data.</h2>
    <form name="xml_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
            Please choose a file: <br /><input name="xl_file" type="file" required/><br />
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
```

The php code:

```
if(isset($_FILES['xl_file']))
{
//upload file to read data from it
    $attach_src=$_FILES['xl_file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_name=time(). $_FILES["xl_file"]["name"];
    $file_name=str_replace(" ","",$file_name);
    $upload = wp_upload_bits($file_name, null, file_get_contents($_FILES["xl_file"]["tmp_name"]));

    include_once(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');
    $inputFileName =$upload['file'];

    try {
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
      echo ('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
    }
 //array of post data
    $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
 //divide the post array into chunks (for larger arrays)
    $listing=array_chunk($sheetData, 50);


    $list=array();
    $images_list=array();
    //Reading images
    $dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )."Images/";
  //get all the images list
    $images_list = glob($dir."*.*",GLOB_NOSORT); 
    apply_filters( 'admin_memory_limit', WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT );



foreach($sheetData as $list_data){


                $list=array();
                  // get post data into $list array
                foreach($list_data as $list_rec){
                    $list[]=$list_rec;

                }
                   //$list = single post array

                    $listing_information = array(
                        'post_title' => addslashes(wp_strip_all_tags($list[0])),
                        'post_content' => addslashes($list[1]),
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'post_status' => 'publish'
                    );
                    $listingid =wp_insert_post( $listing_information );
                    //listingid= post ID
                    //image name that we will found / search in image folder
                    $listing_image_name=trim($list[2]);

                    //listing_image_name
                    $upload_image=array();
            //loop through images array to find the required image
                    foreach($images_list as $img){
            //$img = /home/public_html/my_site/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/image_name.jpg    
// want to extract only image name from $img
                        $image_name = explode('/', $img );
                        $image_name = $image_name[count($image_name)-1];
                        $needle = '.';
                        $listing_image_name_dir = substr($image_name, 0, strpos($image_name, $needle));
                        //match the image name if yes then insert
                        if($listing_image_name == $listing_image_name_dir){
//uploading the image to wordpress 
                            $upload_image = wp_upload_bits($images_list[0], null, file_get_contents($images_list[0]));
                            // Check the type of tile. We'll use this as the 'post_mime_type'.
                            $filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $upload_image['file'] ), null );   
                            $attachment = array(
                                'guid'           => $upload_image['file'], 
                                'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
                                'post_title'     => $listing_image_name,
                                'post_content'   => '',
                                'post_status'    => 'inherit'
                            );

//insert wordpress attachment of uploaded image to get attachmen ID
                            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $upload_image['file']);
//generate attachment thumbnail
                            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $upload_image['file'] ) );
//set this attachment as post featured image
//listingid= post ID
                            set_post_thumbnail( $listingid, $attach_id );
                            break;
                        }//end of if
                    }//end of foreach

                    unset($list);

                    unset($listing_image);
                    unset($upload_image);

                flush();
            }


    }
```